# iOS: Getting crash Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException Can’t add self as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash

I am getting the following error

Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
Can’t add self as subview

I can't figure out where in my code this is occurring or how it is occurring. Can someone please help me figure out? Only a very few people are getting this according to crashlytics (iOS 8 iphone users are experiencing this). Any tips or suggestions is appreciated.

```
0  CoreFoundation                 0x221b0e3f __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2f888c8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x221b0d85 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  UIKit                          0x2565548b -[UIView(Internal)     _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 114
4  UIKit                          0x25655413 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 30
5  UIKit                          0x2581ab69 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 1120
6  UIKit                          0x2565baf5 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 72
7  UIKit                          0x2581a4c5 -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] + 812
8  UIKit                          0x257d8d21 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 2860
9  UIKit                          0x256f7f57 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 422
10 UIKit                          0x256f7d5d -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 44
11 UIKit                          0x256f7cf1 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 184
12 UIKit                          0x2564c677 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 514
13 QuartzCore                     0x25074ccd -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 136
14 QuartzCore                     0x250706b5 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 360
15 QuartzCore                     0x2507053d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
16 QuartzCore                     0x2506ff21 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
17 QuartzCore                     0x2506fd25 CA::Transaction::commit() + 324
18 QuartzCore                     0x25069bfd CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
19 CoreFoundation                 0x221775cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
20 CoreFoundation                 0x22174c8b __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 278
21 CoreFoundation                 0x22175093 __CFRunLoopRun + 914
22 CoreFoundation                 0x220c3621 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
23 CoreFoundation                 0x220c3433 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
24 GraphicsServices               0x294320a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
25 UIKit                          0x256ae359 UIApplicationMain + 1440
26 MyApp                        0x0008346f main (main.m:16)
27 libdyld.dylib                  0x2fe08aaf start + 2
```

Comment: Check all your `addSubview:` calls. One of them probably looks like: `[self addSubview:self]` or `[someViewWithALongName addSubview:someViewWithALongName]`. If you're using names that are similar to each other (i.e. `productLabel` and `productView`) you may not notice when you've used the wrong name.